# Problema con ejercicio de variable local y global en C

Tags: c

realicé el siguiente ejercicio tal y como aparece el ejemplo en un libro:

```
/*4_3.c en prueba*/
#include<stdio.h>
int k=5; /*variable global*/

void main(void){
void f1(void); /*prototipo de función*/
int i;
 for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
    f1();
 }
}

void f1(void){
int k=2 /*variable local*/
k+=k;
printf("\n\nEl valor de la variable local es: %d", k);
::k = ::k + k;
printf("\nEl valor de la variable global es: %d", ::k);
}
```

y se supone que debía obtener un programa como este más o menos:

[image: respuesta_esperada]

pero al compilar me da error, estoy usando en cmd:

```
gcc -o test 4_3.c
```

¿alguién sabe que puede pasar? por que copié el ejemplo tal cual del libro.

Comment: Para próximas ocasiones, ten en cuenta que indicar el error ayuda a que las respuestas sean más certeras. Toda información que puedas aportar ayuda a la hora de resolver el problema.

Comment: @Robby una vez que corrijas lo que te marcaron en las 3 respuestas, [obtendrás el resultado que esperabas](http://ideone.com/Z92UXS)... Estoy votando por cerrar esta pregunta porque es un error tipográfico sin relevancia para futuros lectores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te falta un punto y coma (`;`) al final de la línea `int k=2`.

```
/*4_3.c en prueba*/
#include<stdio.h>
int k=5; /*variable global*/

int main(void){ // <--- cambio void por int
void f1(void); /*prototipo de función*/
int i;
 for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
    f1();
 }
 return 0; // <---- agregado
}

void f1(void){
int k=2; /*variable local*/ // <--- aquí
k+=k;
printf("\n\nEl valor de la variable local es: %d", k);
::k = ::k + k;
printf("\nEl valor de la variable global es: %d", ::k);
}
```

De todas maneras `::` no es ningún operador en C por lo cual deberías compilar con `g++` o bien poner la extensión `.cpp` o `.C` o `.c++` al archivo para decirle a `gcc` que utilice el compilador de C++.

Adicionalmente, lo correcto es que `main` devuelva `int`.

Comment: Gracias Juan Manuel, de gran ayuda tu respuesta, añadí el ";" que faltaba  (python como primer lenguaje me dejó malacostumbrado) pero aun así me daba error, pero al realizar los cambios propuestos y cambiar el gcc por g++ al compilar se solucionó todo.

Answer (score 1):

```
int k=2 /*variable local*/
```

Esa línea tiene que terminar con punto y coma.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Te falta un ;, siempre recuerda  poner ; C es un lenguaje un poco tedioso a veces pero después de que aprendes correctamente este lenguaje ninguno se te resistirá.